# Products Using Placeholder Image in Category View

Tags: database, frontend, product-images

A script was run to clear unused product images to free up space on the server, but instead of clearing unused images, it accidentally cleared a portion of images currently in use by products. The script removed the images from the server as well as records from the database.

Image files were restored to `pub/media/catalog/product` and the following database tables had their data restored:

```
catalog_product_entity_varchar
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value
catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value_to_entity
```

After restoring images and database tables, I have flushed the Cache Storage and Catalog Images Cache and run `php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`. I have also run:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

This has successfully restored all images in the admin and on the product details page, but effected products are showing the placeholder image on the category view.

I just need to find what record is missing that is causing the category view to not read the product images.

Answer (score 0):

Please run this command and check.

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Hope this will work.

Comment: I have already run that command, which restored images in admin and on product details page, but not category view.

Comment: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-PWA-Theming-Layout/Luma-Showing-Placeholders-not-Thumbnail/td-p/413441